# Is the denominator of the passive high pass filter given wrong?

Tags: filter

[image]

Circuit can be found [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_3.html)

The following section from a book called AOE shows the Vout/Vin for a high pass filter:

[image]

But shouldn’t the denominator be square root of the sum of squares of R and Xc? But above the denominator is given as the algebraic sum. Is the above equation wrong? What is the meant by approximation here?

Comment: Is the filter passive or active? You're not showing what Figures 1.91 and 1.92 are.

Comment: passive 1st order: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/fil11.gif?fit=326%2C165

Comment: But what makes it possible to approximate  here? Why are those two equations approximate  ?

Comment: Essentially it's using \$w\$ instead of \$jw\$. For frequencies way below the cutoff frequency, \$wRC\$ will be much smaller than 1 and the denominator will be very close to 1 anyways. For frequencies considerably above the cutoff frequency, \$wRC\$ will be much higher than 1 and the gain will be close to 1 anyways. The approximation will only be off around the cutoff frequency. Regardless, the author seems to be underestimating the reader's math abilities.